# How to use Multiple relationship in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

In my app i have define relationship (profile, user, level) but when I fetch data it is showing an error (`Trying to get property 'email' of non-object`) how can i solve this thank in advance.

this is User Model

```
public function profile()
{
     return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Profile Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id');
}
public function level()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Level::class, 'id');
}
```

Level Model

```
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'level_id');
}
```

This is Controller ProfileController

```
$users = Profile::with(['user', 'level'])->where('is_bd_partner', 'Yes')->get();
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) 
        {
            echo $value->first_name.'<br>';
            echo $value->last_name.'<br>';
            echo $value->user->email.'<br>';
            echo $value->level->level.'<br>';
        }
```

Comment: can you show the output of $users : dump($users); before foreach please ?

Comment: this is dump of user http://prntscr.com/my9awu

Comment: i am using one framework laravel

Comment: Please can you show the migration/table structure for the models?

Answer (score 2):

Note that belongsTo takes `foreign_key` as the first parameter.
So you should change the Profile Model as

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
public function level()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Level::class, 'level_id');
}
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)